# Помогите найти ошибки в JSON

Tags: json

```
{

"adress": [

{

"id": 7E65638C555E2D8743258690004E36DF ,

"numberAddress": 289282 ,

"name": "",

"street": Чертановская улица ,

house": 54к1 ,

flat": 28 ,

"entry : ед.",

"corpus": "",

"building : "",

"doorphone": 28 ,

floor": 5 ,

"phone": +79271234567,

"contaktname": "",

"info": "",

"tara": 0,

"paidcontainer": 0,

"balans": 0,

"status": 0,

"sector": 88,

"contacts": [],

"city : {

"id": 1A34B67224C5E984432586C0003564ED ,

"name": Москва"

}

},

{

"id": 7E65638C555E2D8743258690004E36DF ,

"cntaddress": 322806 ,

"name": "",

"street": улица Мичуринский Проспект, Олимпийская Деревня ,

house": 17 ,

flat": 165 ,

"entry : 3 ,

"corpus": "",

"building : "",

"doorphone": 165 ,

floor": 10 ,

"phone": "",

"contaktname": "",

"info": "",

"tara": 0,

"paidcontainer": 0,

"city : {

"id": 1A34B67224C5E984432586C0003564ED ,

"name": Москва"

}
 

]
 }
```

Comment: JSON Validator вам в помощь...есть множество браузерных вариантов, просто загуглите...

Comment: да пробовал уже не один. не особо смог что-то исправить. спасибо

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вашего вопроса, с чем конкретно у вас возникла сложность при выполнении данной задачи? Какую вообще задачу вы решаете? Откуда вы получили этот невалидный JSON? Опишите подробнее в вопросе, отредактируйте его по кнопке [edit] под вопросом. Без дополнительной информации ваш вопрос не несет пользы для других участников сообщества.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно он должен выглядеть так

```
{
  "adress": [
    {
      "id": "7E65638C555E2D8743258690004E36DF",
      "numberAddress": 289282,
      "name": "",
      "street": "Чертановская улица",
      "house": "54к1",
      "flat": 28,
      "entry": "ед.",
      "corpus": "",
      "building": "",
      "doorphone": 28,
      "floor": 5,
      "phone": "+79271234567",
      "contaktname": "",
      "info": "",
      "tara": 0,
      "paidcontainer": 0,
      "balans": 0,
      "status": 0,
      "sector": 88,
      "contacts": [],
      "city": {
        "id": "1A34B67224C5E984432586C0003564ED",
        "name": "Москва"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "7E65638C555E2D8743258690004E36DF",
      "cntaddress": 322806,
      "name": "",
      "street": "улица Мичуринский Проспект, Олимпийская Деревня",
      "house": 17,
      "flat": 165,
      "entry": 3,
      "corpus": "",
      "building": "",
      "doorphone": 165,
      "floor": 10,
      "phone": "",
      "contaktname": "",
      "info": "",
      "tara": 0,
      "paidcontainer": 0,
      "city": {
        "id": "1A34B67224C5E984432586C0003564ED",
        "name": "Москва"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

ошибка банальная - отсутствие открывающих или закрывающих кавычек во многих места

Comment: валидатор ругается всё равно на 46ю строку. спасибо

Comment: а сейчас? я поправил

Comment: сейчас всё отлично. огромное вам спасибо. всё дело было в кавычках?

Comment: ошибок было много и да, все они из за отсутствия кавычек. Если вопрос решен, то можете нажать на соответствующую кнопку слева от моего ответа

Comment: спасибо ещё раз. я новичок)